# Ultra fast netbook linux distribution (2gb ram)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

i would like to use my older Samsung netbook for some coding  (php, apache, mysql).

But Ubuntu distribution is quite slow.

Can somebody recommend to me some ultra fast and efficient linux distribution for netbooks?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Please guys, don't respond to posts that are clearly off topic. Hit the close button instead. Besides poluting the forum, the user can generally get a much better answer at a forum where it is on-topic.

Comment: I highly recommend you try [Bodhi Linux](http://www.bodhilinux.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into this link [here](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/8-of-the-best-tiny-linux-distros-683552)

Although I would recommend you either of the following 2 distros for small memory consumption systems

1. CentOS minimal ( Just install the xWindow package and you will have a full fledge Centos system with a memory footprint of approximately 300MB)
2. DSL ( Damn Small Linux) is a well renowned linux distro with a 50 MB memory footprint.

I would personally recommend using CentOS since you can easily find packages of almost anything for CentOS without any issue